# How to log value of my .env file in Spring

Tags: java, spring, environment-variables

When I log my env variables in my main application I get null value. How to fix this? Or are there other best practice to check my env variables?

[YAML File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3dYQ.png)

```
SERVER:
  PORT: ${SERVER_PORT}

spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${DB_URL}
    username: ${USERNAME}
    password: ${PASSWORD}
    driverClassName: ${DRIVER_CLASSNAME}

  jpa:
    spring.jpa.database-platform: ${DB_PLATFORM}
```

[Env File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWtqi.png)

```
SERVER_PORT=8070

DB_URL="jdbc:h2:mem:dcbapp"
DRIVER_CLASSNAME="org.h2.Driver"
DB_PLATFORM="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"

WELCOME_MESSAGE="Welcome to the Student App"
```

[My Main Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD3sE.png)

I tried logging using Logger and also a @Value("") annotation but still end up with the same result

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUmJW.png)
package com.example.demo;

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    @Value("${SERVER.PORT}")
    private static String port;




    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        //To display using port variable
        System.out.println("Port: "+ port);
        // To display using System.getenv("PORT")
        System.out.println("Port: "+ System.getenv("PORT"));

    }
}
```

Comment: Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- It should be `@Value("server.port")` instead of `@Value("SERVER.PORT")` and `System.getenv("SERVER_PORT")` instead of `System.getenv("PORT")`.

Comment: Thank for the Info, will refrain from uploading images from now on. 

Update for the server.port I still got the null value

Comment: Please refresh the page and re-read my comment. I updated it.

Comment: I am also not sure whether spring-boot has build-in support for `.env`-files.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, output still the same. Don't know what is the cause of this.

I fixed it by doing this in my main application

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        Environment env = context.getEnvironment();


        String port = env.getProperty("server.port");
        if (port != null) {
            System.out.println("Port: " + port);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Port environment variable is not set.");
        }
}
```